# Could not find the required component 'rosconsole' on macOS

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, rosconsole, roslib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Trying to build ROS melodic on macOS High Sierra I encountered this problem:

```
-- Could NOT find rosconsole (missing: rosconsole_DIR)
-- Could not find the required component 'rosconsole'. The following CMake error indicates that you either need to install the package with the same name or change your environment so that it can be found.
CMake Error at /Users/cameroj/Projects/ros/macos/install_isolated/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:83 (find_package):
  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "rosconsole" with
  any of the following names:

    rosconsoleConfig.cmake
    rosconsole-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "rosconsole" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "rosconsole_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If
  "rosconsole" provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has
  been installed.
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/301298/could-not-find-the-required-component-%27rosconsole%27-on-macos/) by [Josh Cameron](https://answers.ros.org/users/37119/josh-cameron/) on ROS Answers with karma: 16 on 2018-08-22

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Ultimately, I was able to resolve my problem by specifying `rosconsole_DIR` correctly. It took several tries to find the right value of `rosconsole_DIR`:

```
-Drosconsole_DIR=/Users/cameroj/Projects/ros/macos/install_isolated/share/rosconsole/cmake
```

In my case, the root of my ROS project is /Users/cameroj/Projects/ros/macos.

Having fixed this problem for rosconsole, I had the same problem for roslib, which was solved the same way:

```
-Droslib_DIR=/Users/cameroj/Projects/ros/macos/install_isolated/share/roslib/cmake
```

I hope this helps someone out there.

---

Originally posted by [Josh Cameron](https://answers.ros.org/users/37119/josh-cameron/) with karma: 16 on 2018-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-22**:
Some expectation management: compiling ROS from sources on OSX is not a pleasant task. Nor is maintaining such an install. If you have the possibility, are learning and want to focus on ROS itself (instead of solving build issues), see whether you can dual-boot with Ubuntu.

**Comment by [Josh Cameron](https://answers.ros.org/users/37119/josh-cameron/) on 2018-08-22**:
@gvdhoom: You're not kidding about "not a pleasant task". In my case I've already built ROS on an Ubuntu VM but the VM isn't a workable solution for a new use case. Might be able to dual boot, but I'd prefer to work in my macOS environment so I'm going to slog it out a bit longer & see what happens.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-23**:
Unfortunately Apple themselves make this a hard thing to do. There have been many questions posted in the past about why there are no binary distributions of ROS for OSX, and the answers typically go along the line of: it's too much work and there isn't really a simple way to automate it. ..

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-23**:
.. That is definitely true. Especially because of all the dependencies that ROS needs, and the way those are managed on OSX (brew, etc), it's just involved to keep things working. Too brittle. And with things like SIP, they don't get any easier.

Windows development can be difficult too though.